# Changing titleTextAttribute in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, appdelegate

Every since i updated xcode i cant seem to change the `titleTextAttribute`. Now when i use following code i get this error:

> could not find an overload init that accepts this supplied arguments

Code in `appDelegate`:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Ubuntu", size: 17), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Ubuntu-Light", size: 15), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There was a recent change so that `UIFont(name:size:)` returns an optional `UIFont` instance. You'll need to unwrap them to get it to work. Using `!` is the easiest way, but will get you a crash if the font isn't on the system. Try something like:

```
let navbarFont = UIFont(name: "Ubuntu", size: 17) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
let barbuttonFont = UIFont(name: "Ubuntu-Light", size: 15) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: navbarFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: barbuttonFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Nate! Nate! Nate! Nate!

Comment: More info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583346/how-can-i-change-the-font-of-the-back-button-for-my-navigation-bar/28347428#28347428

Answer (score 12):

Swift 4:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
        ]
```

Comment: AppDelegate.shared.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
AppDelegate.shared.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

Answer (score 3):

### Swift 5

```
navBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:titleColor]
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3 you could try the following:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if let navFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 30.0) {
        let navBarAttributesDictionary: [NSObject: AnyObject]? = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
            NSFontAttributeName: navFont
        ]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarAttributesDictionary
    }
```

Comment: Had to change [NSObject:AnyObject] to [String: AnyObject]

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
if let navFont = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 18) {
   let navBarAttributesDictionary: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
   NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor(netHex: Colors.BabyBlue.rawValue),
   NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue): navFont ]
   UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = navBarAttributesDictionary
}
```

Comment: Why are you using all those rawValues? Just type NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor for example, no need to initiate it through (rawValue:).

Answer (score 0):

Setting Title Attributes and NavigationBar background colour may not work for iOS 15 and higher versions.
Please find the following extension to achieve it.

```
extension UINavigationBar {
func setDefaultTint(_ color: UIColor = .black, titleColor: UIColor = .white) {
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = color
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: titleColor]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        barTintColor = color
        titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: titleColor]
    }
}
```

***Note***: call code in `#available(iOS 15, *)` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` from AppDelegate if you want to keep navigation bar configuration throughout the application.
In-case of different colours for different screens? call the function of `setDefaultTint(_)` before creating navigation controller.