# How can I change the font of the back button for my navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How can I change the font of the back button for my navigation bar.

The back button is either "back" or the title from the previous view controller.

I thought this `viewDidLoad` would work:

```
navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "FONTNAME", size: 20)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

but the `leftBarButton?` optional returns `nil`.

Comment: Do you want the font to be the same for every bar button item in the app or just the back button?

Comment: I'm assuming you're going to offer setting it in the app delegate, both solutions would actually be useful to know  :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just tested your code and it seems the reason that line is returning `nil` is actually because `name: "FONTNAME"` returns nil. So if you set that `name` attribute to a valid font name, the code should run without an error -- even if `navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` is explicitly set to nil.

But regardless, also as I've seen through testing, this line won't give you the result you apparently want. The leading `navigationController` optional shouldn't be there since it accesses your `UINavigationController` and not the current view. Simply use the `UIViewController`'s own `navigationItem` property to access its `leftBarButtonItem` directly, ex:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 20)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

**Edit**: From the comment you posted under this answer, it seems as if you don't actually want to set the `leftBarButtonItem` but the `backBarButtonItem` because you don't want to implement a custom action beyond going back to the previous view controller.

So in that previous view controller (i.e. the view before you want to show your custom back button item), you can set your custom back button without an action like so:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
backButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 20)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I know having an invalid font name would cause a crash, I just put that there for a placeholder. 

I figured I would just be able to edit the setTitleTextAttributes() on the button that was already there, as that already navigates back to the previous view, your solution works, but now I have to go and set up the action for it, which seems a bit long winded for essentially what is already there...

Comment: Then don't use `leftBarButtonItem`. Use `backBarButtonItem`. I'll update to explain in a sec...

Answer (score 72):

If you need to change font style **entirely** across you app (aka. each navigation button), preferred method is to use `UIBarButtonItem.appearance()` proxy.

Sample code snippet would look like this:

**SWIFT 3.0+**

```
//make sure font name u use below *actually* exists in the system !
//if it doesn't app will crash because we're force unwrapping an optional (see below) !!!
let customFont = UIFont(name: "customFontName", size: 17.0)!
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: customFont], for: .normal)
```

It is wise to put this code snippet somewhere at the beginning of your `AppDelegate.swift` file because font stylization has to happen each time the app launches. Also, you're safe to put this code in *any other place* (eg. `Presenter` class) where you do your UI stylization and customization. As soon as this code gets executed, all your BarButtons will be customized thereafter.

---

**BUT** as a true Swift , you should first optionally unwrap your font and eventually fallback to system font if it's not found or any other possible issue arise during font loading.

```
var textAttributes: [String:Any]

//custom font setup
let fontColor = UIColor.purple
let barItemCustomFont = UIFont(name: "", size: 14)  //note we're not forcing anything here

//can we use our custom font 
if let customFont = barItemCustomFont {
    //hooray we can use our font 
    textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fontColor, NSFontAttributeName: customFont]
} else {
    // not found -> omit setting font name and proceed with system font
    textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fontColor]
}

//finally
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes, for: .normal)
```

## Real world example

In a real app you would usually need to customize both `UINavigationBar` and `UIBarButton` font style (aside from other parameters) to make them visually consistent.
Here is handy `stylizeNavigationFontOfMyAmazingApp` function you can use:

```
    func stylizeNavigationFontOfMyAmazingApp() {
        //custom font
        let customFont = UIFont(name: "someFancyFont", size: 16)!  //note we're force unwrapping here

        //navigation bar coloring:
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue

        //unique text style:
        var fontAttributes: [String: Any]
        fontAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red, NSFontAttributeName: customFont]

        //navigation bar & navigation buttons font style:
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = fontAttributes
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(fontAttributes, for: .normal)

   }
```

---

#### Advantages of using `appearance()` proxy

- Two liner code snippet for stylizing **every** `UIBarButtonItem` in
  your app/project.
- You can mix `appearance()` proxies of several classes to get truly unique visual style
- If you need further customization control you can re-customize each button further (e.g. placing custom views, button, images, etc) - on specific instance of `UIBarButtonItem`.

#### Reference

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance/1615010-appearance) on `appearance` protocol.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to apply this change to all of your application you can use below code:

**Swift 4**

I've added these lines to `AppDelegate.swift` in `application` function :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "IranSansMobile", size: 20)!
        ]

        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "IranSansMobile", size: 15)!], for: UIControlState.normal)

  return true
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "IranSansMobile", size: 20)!
    ]

    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "IranSansMobile", size: 15)!], for: UIControlState.normal)


    return true
}
```

Comment: It's necessary to also set the attribute `for: .selected` as well, or the button will show in the original font while pressed

Comment: Also need `for: .highlighted` to keep the same font during touch down.

Answer (score 8):

For iOS 13, Swift 5.1:

```
let fontAttr = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: \*your font*\]

let buttonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = fontAttr

let navbarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navbarAppearance.buttonAppearance = buttonAppearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navbarAppearance
```

Comment: This worked for me!

For anyone seeing broken fonts on nav bar buttons for iOS 13, wrapping this in an #ifavailable clause did the trick for me, and drop in the old way of doing it in the else block (For iOS 12 and below)

Comment: This worked but it overrides my title font  any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, I wondered why setTitleTextAttribute wasn't working in my > iOS13 code. `buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = fontAttr` was what I needed.

Comment: didn't work for me. in which lifecycle method do we need to write this?

Answer (score 3):

When you are sure you've already set a `UIBarButtonItem` you can do:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.title = "myTitle"
```

To change e.g. the color you can do the following:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

When you haven't set it in your storyboard you can do:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
```

For changing the font, do the following:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "FONTNAME", size: 20)!], forState: .Normal)
```

Maybe I should mention that you mustn't use self.`navigationController` because when setting the navigationController's buttons they aren't displayed on the screen so as a result the buttons which are on the screen and had been set in the storyboard have to be `self.navigationItem`...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've not the UIBarButtonItem in this view, its being inherited from the previous view in this case. Even when using the last two lines of your answer (without self) its still returning nil

Comment: Actually it cannot happen that it is returning nil when you set it manually. You said it's inherited from the previous view - could you give us that info?

Answer (score 3):

SWIFT 3

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Open Sans", size: 15)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Open Sans", size: 15)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: Any reason to repeat everything whats already been answered here ?