# How to change font of navigation items?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a couple of navigation items (Back Button, Save Button) on my NavigationBar.
I tried looking for relevant answers, I find either an outdated answer or just none.

I tried setTitleTextAttributes on the navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem but did not work.

I managed to change the font of the NavigationBar title but that's it. Using self.navigationBar.titleTextAttribues, same method done with the nav items but not working.

**EDIT:** Found a solution, but I have to add this on EVERY view controller's viewWillAppear

```
let barBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Test", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "backButtonPressed")
barBtn.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: FONT_HERE, size: 12)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(barBtn, animated: false)
```

Then adding the backButtonPressed function where I call a popViewControllerAnimated.

What do you think, guys? Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the font of the back button for my navigation bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583346/how-can-i-change-the-font-of-the-back-button-for-my-navigation-bar)

Comment: Followed it, not working.

Comment: you can assign a custom label to self.navigationItem.titleView

Comment: All your questions in one place : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28347428/469614

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the appearance protocol : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html

Here is an example of how I customized the appearance of a navigation bar.

// Navigation bar title
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{                                                       NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"myfont" size:20.0f],
                                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]
                                                            }];

```
// Navigation bar buttons and background
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor teal];
[UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = NO;
```

Comment: UINavigationBar has no member 'setTitleTextAttributes'