# Change global UIBarButtonItem appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am using Swift to build an iOS application and would like to change the global **`appearance`** of `UIBarButtonItem`. I am doing this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Apple's documentation says this:

```
func setTitleTextAttributes(_ attributes: [String : AnyObject]?, forState state: UIControlState)
```

for `UIBarItem`. But when I try to do this, it only expects `self: UIBarItem`. Has anyone else encountered this? Is it a bug in Xcode or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This has been answered many times before. Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28347428/469614

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you tried realising it with `UIAppearance` protocol? It should be used for global сustomizing some visual classes. I can suggest your some code like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UINavigationBar.classForCoder()]).setTitleTextAttributes(["attribute" : "value"], forState: .Normal)
```

Hopes it is clear from the code the way in works and how you can enwide it.

Answer (score 8):

Call `setTitleTextAttributes` on the `UIBarButtonItem` [appearance proxy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/):

Swift 3:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([key : value], for: .normal)
```

Swift 2.x:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([key : value], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```