# How to set custom font for backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

When there was no left bar items, navigation bar will gives a `backBarButtonItem` like `<Back`. But I can't find anyway to set font for it. Please help me! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use attributed text --- et barButtonBackStr = "< Back"
let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter-Bold", size: 18)!]
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: barButtonBackStr, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "barButtonBack:")
newBackButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton

Comment: Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347428/469614

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: 16)!,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:.red], for: .normal)
```

Objective-C:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                          shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:15.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Can you pls provide this answer in Swift?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Actually I have not worked with swift.

Comment: UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName("Futura-Medium"), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

Comment: This doesn't work. Back button font stays system font.

Comment: @coolcool1994 Please check edited answer.